# Removing Header and Footer from CMS page

Tags: cms, header, footer, page-content

is it possible to remove both the header and footer and only display the contents of a CMS page?  If so, how?

Currently the html looks something like this by default:

```
<body class=" cms-page-view cms-info-shipping cms-info-shipping">
    <div id="header">...</div>
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <div id="footer">...</div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for any elucidation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

when editing the cms page, there's a field called layout update. use this code in it:

```
<reference name="root">
    <remove name="header"/>
    <remove name="footer"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: This will work but only if the layout you are using have this names for the header/footer block

Comment: and if you're not using certain plugins, and heavy caching... it was a raw magento question, no other specs. by default, those blocks are called that way in magento. there's no need for an extra file (plus a package and a theme) just to remove the header and footer. it's a good approach to other things, but i wouldn't use it in this case

Comment: @Cristi Is possible to change header and footer for multi-store with the same theme.

Comment: How to add two header for multi store

Comment: @zus yes it is, but it depends on your setup

Answer (score 4):

CMS pages have a layout associated to it.

You can create a custom layout and remove everything you dont want to have in the page and then assign it to the CMS page in the Design tab.

Answer (score 4):

In admin section there are options to set the layout of CMS page. Please choose **empty**.

It will remove the header and footer and only shows the content of CMS page.

```
CMS > Edit CMS Page > Design > Layout > empty.
```

Comment: @mishra : If you using multi-store, this trick not working.