# Removing footer for selected CMS page?

Tags: magento-1.9, footer, cms-pages

I am developing an Ecommerce site and I want to **remove the footer** from selected CMS page.

I have refered this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46953/removing-header-and-footer-from-cms-page), which say to remove the footer from entire CMS pages, but I dont need to remove for the entire pages.

So can anyone say me how to overcome in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ref is the answer.

You just need to add that block of code in each cms you want to remove.

Go to your cms page and go to `Design` then in `Custom Design` field add this block:

**CMS > Edit CMS Page > Design > Custom Design**

```
<reference name="root">
    <remove name="header"/>
    <remove name="footer"/>
</reference>
```